# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" for contextual data

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm running the code that Google/ dialogflow provided on their website ([Link)](https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent-advanced-concepts/create-a-confirmation-step#how_the_code_works) and for some reason it keeps throwing this error everytime I trigger the intent I'm wanting to invoke:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Here's the code I have:

```
app.intent('Make Appointment' , (conv) => {
// This variable needs to hold an instance of Date object that specifies the start time of the appointment.
const dateTimeStart = convertTimestampToDate(conv.parameters.date, 
conv.parameters.time);
// This variable holds the end time of the appointment, which is calculated by adding an hour to the start time.
const dateTimeEnd = addHours(dateTimeStart, 1);
// Convert the Date object into human-readable strings.
const appointmentTimeString = getLocaleTimeString(dateTimeStart);
const appointmentDateString = getLocaleDateString(dateTimeStart);
// The checkCalendarAvailablity() function checks the availability of the time slot.
return checkCalendarAvailablity(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd).then(() => {
  // The time slot is available.
  // The function returns a response that asks for the confirmation of the date and time.
  conv.ask(`Okay, ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString}. Did I get that right?`);
}).catch(() => {
  // The time slot is not available.
  conv.add(`Sorry, we're booked on ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString}. Is there anything else I can do for you?`);
  // Delete the context 'MakeAppointment-followup' to return the flow of conversation to the beginning.
  conv.context.delete('MakeAppointment-followup');
});
});



 app.intent('Make Appointment - yes', (conv) => {
// Get the context 'MakeAppointment-followup'
      const context = conv.context.get('MakeAppointment-followup');
// This variable needs to hold an instance of Date object that specifies the start time of the appointment.
const dateTimeStart = convertTimestampToDate(context.parameters.date, context.parameters.time);
// This variable holds the end time of the appointment, which is calculated by adding an hour to the start time.
const dateTimeEnd = addHours(dateTimeStart, 1);
// Convert the Date object into human-readable strings.
const appointmentTimeString = getLocaleTimeString(dateTimeStart);
const appointmentDateString = getLocaleDateString(dateTimeStart);
// Delete the context 'MakeAppointment-followup'; this is the final step of the path.
conv.context.delete('MakeAppointment-followup');
// The createCalendarEvent() function checks the availability of the time slot and marks the time slot on Google Calendar if the slot is available.
return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd).then(() => {
  conv.add(`Got it. I have your reservation scheduled on ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString}!`);
}).catch(() => {
  conv.add(`Sorry, something went wrong. I couldn't book the ${appointmentDateString} at ${appointmentTimeString}. Is there anything else I can help you with?`);
});
});
```

(sorry for the long code, but I feel it's necessary for the question)

All these two functions do is makes an appointment (or booking) and adds a confirmation step to it. So for example, it would look something like this if all went well:

```
User: I'd like to make an appointment
bot: Sure, what day works for you?
User: Tomorrow
bot: what time?
User: At 6 pm
bot: Okay, February 11 at 6pm, did I get that right?
User: Yes   // Part where it stops working
Bot: Great, I have your appointment booked for February 11 at 6pm!  // App crashes at this part
```

I'm suspect (although highly doubtful) that the reason could be that in the examples they were using "agent" and the old syntax, where as I'm using the AOG syntax.

Any suggestions/ help are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close.

These should be the property `contexts` with an "s" at the end.

It looks like you're using the actions-on-google library, which typically has a `conv` object and uses the [`contexts`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.dialogflowconversation.html#contexts) property to access the contexts with `get()`, `set()`, and `delete()` methods.

If you used the dialogflow-fulfillment library (which you didn't), it tends to have an `agent` object and use the [`context`](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/aaade16f72a799610ae6ef168c8b47780ae58e6e/src/v2-agent.js#L111) property (without the "s") to access similar `get()`, `set()`, and `delete()` methods.

Comment: I'm getting the same error now only for the 'Parameters' object. I thought it would be the same fix but I still get the error at the same spot. Is it supposed to be just "param" or "parameter "instead of "parameters"? Thanks for the help

Comment: The attribute is supposed to be `parameters`. It may be best (or easiest) to post the code and error you're getting as a new SO question, since it sounds like a different issue. (Again, posting the whole code was good and helped! So as much as you can show, the better.)

Comment: Sure thing, I will post it

Comment: I'm using the fulfilment library with node but the context is still undefined.
function confirmAccount(agent) {
let myContext = agent.context.get('context-name');
....
}
Thats the code I'm using

Comment: @theAuthor - If this doesn't answer your question, go ahead and post a new one, showing all your code, and providing as much detail (error messages) as you can.